# How can I Run NBench benchmarks in a particular order

Tags: c#

I have a set of [NBench](https://github.com/petabridge/NBench) benchmarks that I want to run in a particular order. They will use each other's results to save time (it's a big data set).

How can I specify this order? The tests are mainly executed using the NBench.Runner executable.

Their default order is at least not alphabethic, I don't know if it's any particular order, but I'd like to prescribe one.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Hi there. How about the welcoming upvote?

Comment: Wtf... Read the tour, ask a goot question and you will get your "welcoming upvote" ....

Comment: What can be improved with the question?